# Is there a way to access the weight of an edge using Repast4Py's network module?

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, repast-simphony, repast-hpc, repast4py

The Repast4py API documentation states there are ways to [add edges](https://repast.github.io/repast4py.site/apidoc/source/repast4py.network.html#repast4py.network.DirectedSharedNetwork.add_edge) with weights in a network. Similarly, it states ways to access the [number of edges](https://repast.github.io/repast4py.site/apidoc/source/repast4py.network.html#repast4py.network.DirectedSharedNetwork.num_edges) a given vertex has. However, it doesn't seem there is a way to access the weight of a given vertex. Is there any way to access the weight of an edge between two vertices using the Repast4py network module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Repast4Py network object contains a graph field that is a networkx Graph object. This provides most of the non-distributed network functionality. Here's an example from the repast4py unit tests that use it to get an edge, and then get the 'weight' attribute of that edge.

```
g = DirectedSharedNetwork('network', comm)
g.add_edge(agents[5], agents[6], weight=12)
edge = g.graph.edges[agents[5], agents[6]]
self.assertEqual(12, edge['weight'])
```

The shared networks tests at

https://github.com/Repast/repast4py/blob/develop/tests/shared_network_tests.py

have additional examples of working with edges. Also see the networkx documentation.

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/index.html